# How can I allow remote access to my Laravel-React application's database for user registration from another laptop?

Tags: mysql, laravel, networking, network-programming, ip

I have developed an application using Laravel and ReactJs, which is running locally on my laptop with XAMPP. I want to give remote access to another laptop so that users can register and sign up from that laptop. Currently, I can access the application using my laptop's IP address, but users from the other laptop are unable to send data to the database.

Can someone please guide me on how to enable remote access to my database, so that users from another laptop can register and sign up on my application?

Here are some details about my setup:

I'm using XAMPP to run my MySQL database
My Laravel application is running on localhost:8000

I've already tried updating my database configuration to allow remote connections, but I'm still unable to connect from the other laptop.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!